# Can I feed credentials to gsutil on an untrusted system?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am logged onto a shared system that I do not own and I have access to the gsutil command on that system.

I would like to use gsutil on that system to manipulate some google cloud data (download backup, etc.) but does that mean I have to create local files with my credentials or private keys in them ?

This bothers me because this is not my own system and I don't trust these sensitive credentials resting on a shared system ...

Is there a way to keep the credentials local, on my machine, and run gsutil remotely, like this:

ssh user@untrusted.com gsutil blah blah blah -C ./my/local/config.key

... so I keep the keys/creds local, and run gsutil remotely, over SSH ?

Comment: In order to access private data in Cloud Storage bucket you need to authorize your credentials (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/config). As such, a config file is created locally with credentials and OAuth2 settings.

Comment: Right ... I am not sure you understand what I'm getting at here.  The idea is I would be on one UNIX system, with my credentials in a local file, and then I would run gsutil _over ssh_ on a remote system, and feed my local keys/creds to it from my local system ... that way gsutil runs on the remote system, but I never have to store my credentials there.

Answer (score 1):

What if you ran `gsutil auth login` on the untrusted system to get credentials, run your other gsutil commands, then end your session with `gsutil auth revoke`? While it might leave something behind that might *look* like credentials on the untrusted filesystem, they will be gibberish to Google; they won't be valid for authentication.

This scenario assumes: (a) that the untrusted system's `gsutil` command and libraries are trustworthy (e.g., they won't try to cache your credentials somewhere else) and (b) that the root account of the untrusted system is not actively trying to snoop on your gsutil credentials during the session. The window of vulnerability, i.e. your attack surface, is limited to the period of time between the `auth` and `revoke` commands.

Another option might be to create and mount an encrypted FUSE filesystem, but the attack surface is the same: while you are using the `gsutil` command to do work, it's using your valid credentials, so your exposure is the same. For that matter, even if you could pass the credentials over a socket or named pipe through your ssh connection to the `gsutil` command, if gsutil has been modified to capture your credentials, you're vulnerable until the credentials are revoked.

I know it expands the scope of your question, but know what attack vectors you are concerned about might help us hack solutions to mitigate your concerns. Just calling a system "untrusted" can mean a lot of different things.